# postgresql: Update array with latest n items

Tags: postgresql

I have a SQL table,

```
id | name | friends
-------------------
1 | test1 | [fr2, fr1]
```

Now, I want to add 3rd friend as fr3, but want too keep the size as 2 always, so my updated friend list will be `[fr3, fr2]`

How I can update the array with latest n items always?
I can do by array_append and then remove 3rd element, but that will be 2 queries, is there any way, I can achieve that in a single query?

With regards,
-M-

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table
SET friends = ARRAY[fr3, friends[1]]
WHERE id = 1
```

Will work, but since the size of the array is always going to be 2 wouldn't it be safer and simpler to just make 2 separate columns instead? You could always construct the friends array in the select query if having an array as output is really a must.

Comment: I didn't downvote it someone else did. For cases with size n you could update friends to fr3 || friends[1:(n-1)] instead where || appends fr3 to the start of the array. Please do mention the correct size in the question as some solutions to the above question might not be extendable for larger sizes.